# Applying multiple pivot table filters from a table

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I am trying to filter a Pivot Table based on a list of values in a table.

```
Table2:
Selected Months    Selected Years
9                  2018
6
```

The available values for filters on the pivot table are 8,9,6, and 3, in that order.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
    Sub ReportMonth()

    Dim pt1 As PivotTable
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

       Set tbl = Worksheets(6).ListObjects("Table2")
       Set pt1 = Worksheets(5).PivotTables("PivotTable3")

   'Clear the pivot cache and clear the pivot filter choices of old data.
   'Enable multiple filter selections

    pt1.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    pt1.PivotCache.Refresh
    pt1.PivotFields("Month").EnableMultiplePageItems = True

    'y is the counter for Pivot filter items.
    'x is the counter for rows in Table 2 

    With pt1.PivotFields("Month")

            .ClearAllFilters

            On Error Resume Next

            For x = 1 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count
               For y = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
                      If .PivotItems(y).Name = tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 1).Value Then _
                        .PivotItems(y).Visible = True Else _
                        .PivotItems(y).Visible = False

               Next y
            Next x

   End With

End Sub
```

With the above code, filter name "3" is visible, but 3 isn't even in the table.  I get the same result  if I change `.PivotItems(y).Name` to `.PivotItems(y).Value`.  If I change from `For y = 1` to `For y =2`, filter name "8" is visible and it isn't in the table either.

I put a message box in the for loops to return the values of x and y and the corresponding filter and table values.  Those are executing as expected.

Anyone know how I can do this?